# Google emoji Issue

Tags: android, emoji, google-fonts

Hi guys I am working on a chat application. And now i have to implement emoji in my android app. There is an web app also and i have to chat with web app also. and they use google noto emoji so i have to use this in my android app also.i am getting emoji from server side like this

D/messagerecived:

know my queries are
1. how to show it in textview .as its a link of emoji which are on server.
2. how to send my emoji so web app can read .
3. how to use google noto imoji in android app.

I am not able to post any code because I don't have any idea. How to handle this?

Comment: <img src="https://www.gochatin.com/cdn/emoji/v1.0/assets/png/master/emoji_u1f606.png" class="_xs emoji_u1f606">  . this is how i am getting the emoji from web app

Comment: My advice is: Use this [site](http://www.iemoji.com) to copy your desired emojis and save to your server as you want.

Comment: thanks emilio Fonseca but how to show it in textview. sorry but i am quite new with emoji

Comment: 1. Copy the emoji from the site I have mentioned. 2. Paste in your server, or wherever you want. 3. Get the string in your app. 4. use textView.setText(emojiText).

Comment: emoji already copied in my web app and i am getting in chat like this     D/sendtext: <img src="https://www.gochatin.com/cdn/emoji/v1.0/assets/png/master/emoji_u1f606.png" class="_xs emoji_u1f606">    now my question is how to show it in  textview  and how to implement a emoji from android side also.